# FFmpeg Fade Out Audio Filter (afade) not being Applied to Track Clipped Iteratively

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, fluent-ffmpeg

I am trying to split a track into multiple fixed-sized (30-second) clips, each with a (5-second) fade-in / fade-out at the beginning and end, respectively. I'm using `node-fluent-ffmpeg` to interface with `ffmpeg` and saving each of the `ffmpeg` commands in an array of ES6 Promises that I later execute using `Promise.all()`.

I am able to clip the tracks and add the fade-in filter successfully, but for some reason the fade-out filter is only applied to the first clip of the track. I have looked around for answers both in the `ffmpeg` and `node-fluent-ffmpeg` documentation ([here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afade-1) and [here](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#audio-options)), but there is no mention of issues arising from applying fade-out filters to a track that is being clipped multiple times.

My code is very similar to the snippet below, with the audio filters being applied in sequence using the `audioFilters` method. Note that I have tried leaving only the fade-out filter, but the problem persists. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var promises = [];
const duration = track.duration;
const interval = 30;
const fade = 5;             
const bitrate = 128;        

for (var i = 0; i <= Math.floor(duration) - interval; ++i) {
    const start = i;            // Start second.      
    const end = start + interval;
    const mp3 = `${new ObjectId().toHexString()}.mp3`;

    var command = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ffmpeg(path).setStartTime(start)
                    .audioBitrate(bitrate)
                    .audioFilters([
                        {
                            filter: 'afade',
                            options: `t=in:ss=${start}:d=${fade}`
                        },
                        {
                            filter: 'afade',
                            options: `t=out:st=${end - fade}:d=${fade}`
                        }
                    ])
                    .duration(interval)
                    .on('error', (err) => {
                        reject("An error occurred while clipping.");
                    })
                    .on('end', () => {
                        resolve(`Finished processing ${output}.`);
                    })
                    .save(mp3);
    });
    promises.push(command);     
}
```

And here is my `ffmpeg` version information:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.6 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.6 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while of tinkering around, clipping different tracks with the code above, I figured out the issue.

#### The Problem

The problem was with how I kept track of the `start` and `end` times for the fades. It turns out that the times for the fade were being measured with respect to the 30-second clips, not the original track itself. I, on the other hand, kept increasing the `start` and `end` times using the loop below, thinking the fade was applied at the time step in relation to the original track.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= Math.floor(duration) - interval; ++i) {
    const start = i;            // Start second.      
    const end = start + interval;
    ...
```

So by updating the `start` and `end` values with the loop, I was going beyond the end of the 30-second clip when I applied the audio filters.

```
.audioFilters([
    {
        filter: 'afade',
        options: `t=in:ss=${start}:d=${fade}`
    },
    {
        filter: 'afade',
        options: `t=out:st=${end - fade}:d=${fade}`
    }
])
```

That is why I could only hear the fade out for the first clips. The fade-in was not working either, but it was harder to notice, because the first few clips would have a fade in that sounded natural (even though it was also moving up the track and eventually not being applied).

#### The Solution

Turns out it was super simple. I just needed to replace the values in the `options` key so that the `start` for the fade in was always `0` and the `start` for the fade out was always the interval length (30) minus the fade duration (3).

```
.audioFilters([
    {
        filter: 'afade',
        options: `t=in:ss=0:d=${fade}`
    },
    {
        filter: 'afade',
        options: `t=out:st=${interval - fade}:d=${fade}`
    }
])
```

It was a simple issue in the end. Nevertheless, it's good to point out that if you're clipping and applying a fade at the same time, you need to make sure your times are with regards to the clipped track, not the original one.